# Problems with Java UML Class using Mutators and Accessors

Tags: java, uml, driver, accessor, mutators

I am suppose to make a Driver called Black Jack and a Class program called Card. I have not made the Driver class yet because the professor asked us to do the class program Card first. This is what the teacher has said to use:

[Teacher File of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0wYY.jpg)

Above is the file describing what I am to use. ***ABSOLUTELY USE NO ARRAYS OR ARRAY LIST***, we have not learned that yet and are only allowed to use things we have learned. I have asked a lot of people for help and they always say use arrays and dont understand why I cant use them.

My code so far... Sorry the tabs and spacings are not right I usually figure those out later on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Card
{

private final int MAX = 13;
private int face, suit, points, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Ace, Jack, Queen, King;
prive int randomNumber = new newCard();
//CONSTRUCTORS

public Card() {
randomNumber = newCard()
    }

public Card(int faceValue,int suitValue) {
        //face
        Ace = 1;
        Jack = 11;
        Queen = 12;
        King = 13;

        //suit
        Hearts = 1;
        Diamonds = 2;
        Clubs = 3;
        Spades = 4;

    }

//^^^^^^^
//Mutators

public void setFace(int face)
{
face = face
 }

public void setSuit(int suit)
{
suit = suit
    }


//Accessors

public int getFace()
{
    return face;}

public int getSuit()
{
    return suit;}

public int getPoints()
{
    return points;}



//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

public String toString()
    {
        return "Players cards are " + " ";

    }

}
```

My problem Is i have no idea what needs to be done with the mutators I have been putting face = face but its not working out, Also how am i suppose to output the toString method Because im not quiet understanding how the whole face and suit thing is suppose to work the suits is like hearts = 1 and faces are like Jacks =11 I am thinking my program would get confused and output the wrong ones.

Comment: First try this.face = face that should do the assignment in setFace. Same for suit. Your default constructor needs to use the java.util.Random class to generate your card values. getPoints should calculate a cards value based on the file you have been given i.e. if face card = 10 etc.

Comment: I did what you said teh face = face works find I keep trying the random number method but No matter what I get an error cannot find symbol, am I writing it wrong?

Comment: @onesixtyfourth You should put your comment as an answer and get the checked answer for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

First try this.face = face that should do the assignment in setFace. Same for suit. Your default constructor needs to use the java.util.Random class to generate your card values. getPoints should calculate a cards value based on the file you have been given i.e. if face card = 10 etc